# Upgrading ngrx 2 -> 4. Having issue with typing in de-structuring array

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

The error is saying that it's expecting a comma after the `action` parameter in the `.map`.

There's also an error when hovering over `DataActions.AddDataAction` which says `Tuple type '[Action, AppStore]' with length '2' cannot be assigned to tuple with length '5'`

```
@Effect() addData$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(DataActions.ADD_DATA)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .map(([action: DataActions.AddDataAction, store: AppState]) => [action.payload, reducer.dataResults(store)])
    .etc...
```

---

Here's  the relevant packages and their versions in my `package.json`

```
"@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1",
"typescript": "~2.4.0",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

withLastFrom() actually returns a Tuple type and to declare type of each element within a Tuple, we need to do something like

```
map(([action, store]: [DataActions.AddDataAction, AppState])=>
```